# How to center text in a table row, so it was always at the center of the visible area of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, row

Please someone can help me with this task. I want to center text in the table row ('Some text here...') so that it was always in the middle of the visible area of the screen. The table will have horizontal scrolling.

```css
.compare-content {
  max-width: 480px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.compare-content table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.compare-content table caption {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 39px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CECECE;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CECECE;
}
.compare-content table tr {
  line-height: 25px;
}
.compare-content table td {
  padding: 0 10px;
  min-width: 145px;
}
.compare-content tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  color: #898989;
}
```

```html
<div class="compare-content">
  <table class="total">
    <caption>Summary</caption>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="100%">Some text here...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>text1</td>
      <td>text2</td>
      <td>text3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="100%">Some text here...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>text4</td>
      <td>text5</td>
      <td>text6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="100%">Some text here...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>text7</td>
      <td>text8</td>
      <td>text9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="100%">Some text here...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>text10</td>
      <td>text11</td>
      <td>text12</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i can suggest you example, i prepare fiddle for you - https://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/vuxzfvnu/

It works as long you dont have vertical scrolling for you table, but if you dont it all works just fine:

Here's CSS and HTML:

```css
.compare-content {
  max-width: 480px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.compare-content table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.compare-content table caption {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 39px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CECECE;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CECECE;
}
.compare-content table tr {
  line-height: 25px;
}
.compare-content table td {
  padding: 0 10px;
  min-width: 145px;
}
.compare-content tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  color: #898989;
}

.total tr td
{
  border : 0px #000 solid;
}

.fix {
  position: absolute;
  width: 455px;
  left: 10px;
  border : 0px #000 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="compare-content">
  <table class="total">
    <caption>Summary</caption>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="100%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="100%" class="fix">Some text here.. 1.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>text1</td>
      <td>text2</td>
      <td>text3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="100%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="100%" class="fix">Some text here.. 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>text4</td>
      <td>text5</td>
      <td>text6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="100%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="100%" class="fix">Some text here.. 3.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>text7</td>
      <td>text8</td>
      <td>text9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="100%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="100%" class="fix">Some text here.. 4.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>text10</td>
      <td>text11</td>
      <td>text12</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but in the original, this table is large and there is vertical scrolling. Layout made for mobile screens. Need some other solution.

Comment: I checked again your option using position: absolute; It works!! Very grateful for the help. Thanks!

Comment: @Vasilij Altunin When I copy/paste the code you've provided with absolute positioning it doesn't work as it does in the code snippet.  Even in the fiddle you provide - I changed fixed to absolute and it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you find any better alternative for this?

Comment: I use flex for this today, it works just fine just use display: flex; and other flex stuff